Exercise $39$ of John A.Rice book Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis
I am studying the book "Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis" by John A. Rice. In Chapter 4, I encountered an exercise that I am struggling to solve, and I would appreciate at least a hint to help me proceed.
Exercise 39:
Suppose a segment of DNA of length $N = 1,000,000$ is to be shotgun sequenced with fragments of length $L_F = 1000$.

a. How many fragments would be needed so that the probability of an individual site being covered is greater than 0.99?
b. With this choice, how many sites would you expect to be missed?

Let $x$ be the number of fragments. I believe I should estimate the probability of a site being present in at least one fragment as a function of $x$. If a site $s$ is within the first $10^6 - 10^3$ positions, then all fragments with left endpoints between $s-1000$ and $s$ will contain the site $s$, as will all fragments with right endpoints between $s + 1$ and $s + 1000$. However, I am unsure how to model the distribution of these fragment endpoints. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

If your shotgun model is such that any site has $L_F/N$ change of being covered by a random fragment, then you only need to solve for $x$ satisfying $(1-L_F/N)^x < 0.01$, which is about $4603$.

For (b), you could start by finding the probability a particular site is missed by all the fragments.

@angryavian, thanks I found the point in the book where the author defines what is the shotgun model considered.

Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its
wiki.
